# THREE JS applying Gradient to imported Models

Tags: javascript, three.js

The difference between the following two spheres - in terms of how their gradient colors were applied, comes down to one statement:

```
sphereGeometry = sphereGeometry.toNonIndexed();
```

[image]

[image]

Being that I really like the smoother look that `.toNonIndexed()` gives us, I tried applying it to some of the imported “.glb” models available on the THREE.js GIT - but it’s not working.

For example, here’s what happens when I use the horse model available here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/gltf/Horse.glb

[image]

It basically completely ignore my colors and defaults to red and black for some reason.

But when I comment out the `.toNonIndexed()` line, it gives me the colors I asked for - except you definitely see the triangles, which is the look I'm trying to avoid:

[image]

Here's my code for loading the object:

```
function loadAny3DModel() {
    loader.load("./Horse.glb", function(theHorse) {
       console.log("===>'theHorse' has arrived!!!\n");

       var horseScene = theHorse.scene;
       horseMesh = horseScene.children[0]; 
                
       var horseGeometry = horseMesh.geometry; 
       let horseMat = horseMesh.material;
       var horseVertexPositionsArray = horseGeometry.attributes.position;

       // Here's the command that isn't working:
       // horseGeometry = horseGeometry.toNonIndexed(); 
       // horseVertexPositionsArray = horseGeometry.attributes.position;

        let theColor = new THREE.Color();
        let colorsArray = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < horseVertexPositionsArray.count; i++) {
          let randC1 = "purple"; 
          let randC2 = "white";
          let chosenColor = i % 2 == 0 ? randC1 : randC2;
          theColor.set(chosenColor);
          colorsArray.push(theColor.r, theColor.g, theColor.b);
        }
        horseGeometry.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colorsArray, 3));
        horseMat.vertexColors = true;

        render();
        scene.add(horseScene);

    }
}
```

What should I be doing to get the smoother gradients going?

=====================================================================

UPDATE:

Here is a very rough idea of what I'm trying to do: extend a gradient over an entire model, as opposed to every single triangle that is forming the model. (Compare this image to the one above.)

[image]

Comment: You can't avoid the triangles on the horse GLTF. It's a very low-polygon model, so you're always gonna be able to see the geometry. Maybe you'd like to import it into a 3D editor like Blender and subdivide it so the geometry becomes smoother and more high-density, then you can export it as GLTF again.

Comment: @Marquizzo I understand what you're saying but even if I were to alter the model's geometry in Blender and make it less triangular, the problem would remain the same, and that is that when I import the model into `THREE.js` and call `.toNonIndexed()` on its geometry, all my colors would disappear completely. That's what I need help with. Figuring out the work-around for this so it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment in the following line...

```js
horseGeometry = horseGeometry.toNonIndexed();
```

...it means you create a new (!) geometry. As long as you don't assign the geometry back to `Mesh.geometry`, this code won't have any effect. So the fix is to add the following line after using `toNonIndexed()`:

```js
horseMesh.geometry = horseGeometry;
```

Comment: Ok it's still not working. But I made a jsfiddle to make life easier: https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/sbvr9mxd/14/

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. I've enhanced the official example with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/zksmgrod/

Comment: Thank you for fixing my fiddle.  OK, so now the colors are appearing again - and thank you, because you made them work with using `.toNonIndexed` in the code. However, they're still not smooth like they are with the Spheres example I gave in my original question.  And that’s still the main objective of the question: to have gradients extend smoothly over the entire model - as opposed to be applied to every single triangle in the model.
I just quickly made a very rough image in Photoshop to illustrate what I mean - please see above for the update.
So is this possible to do?

Comment: Check out https://jsfiddle.net/awLr5j7m/1/. Notice that the horse has no vertex normals and thus the model is flat shaded. You need to disable flat shading and manually compute vertex normals to get a better result.

Comment: Oh yeah - this looks exactly like what I need! I'll take a look at the code and try to figure it out - thank you!

Comment: For some reason the solution you provided here - which works perfectly when I import `.glb` files, is not working for `.obj` files.  I posted a new question about this - would love your thoughts. Here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181007/three-js-fails-to-apply-gradient-colors-to-imported-obj-file